# Searching for Registry Values in Uninstall using Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file

If you are asking why am I using Batch and not PS or something else, this is the way it was made, and I cannot change it. Please just any help for batches.

Long story short, I have a batch program that runs for our company. It will be used by the Hardware department for post configuration on all computers going out to the users.

I have completed the entire portion, but ran into one issue. I have a section dedicated to checking whether a program exists based on the uninstall section of the registry. Normally, most programs, keep the GUID the same throughout. Apparently Screen Connect decides to change their GUID, as I found on 6 different computers, a different GUID in the uninstall.

I know how to regquery to search within a key for a value, I.E.

Using this example as AnyConnect uses a text key rather than a GUID {XXX}

```
:reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET AnyConnect=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET AnyConnect=No
```

But, I was wondering if there is a way to check for values within keys within a key.

I.E. `....CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{GUID} "Value"`

ALMOST AS SOMETHING LIKE:

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.......\Uninstall\"  /V *******  ^|findstr /ri "ScreenConnect"') do set /a ID=%%a + 0
```

Or whatever it is, as I do not know which switches to use.

The issue here is it would search Uninstall, which has no values, as it is a parent folder for the GUIDs.

Since I do not know what the GUID is going to be, is there a way for me to search all of the keys under \Uninstall and the values of them in one reg Query command?

If that makes sense.

Let me know if you have any questions.

beta Redacted code.

This is somewhat old, so there are a few errors, but you will get the general idea.

```
@echo OFF

:check_Permissions
cls
    echo Administrative permissions required. 
    net session >nul 2>&1
    if %errorLevel% == 0 (
        echo Success: Administrative permissions confirmed. && goto MoveForward
    ) else (
        echo Failure: Please re-run as an Administrator.
        pause
        exit
    )
goto :check_Permissions
    pause

:MoveForward
cls
echo Admininstrative Privs Confirmed
pause
cls

echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
echo                          Current Info
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"Domain"
echo User Name:                   %username%
echo.
echo.
for /f "tokens=9 delims==" %%I in ('WHOAMI /FQDN') do set "Domain=%%I"
set "Line1=Current Domain: %Domain%"
echo.
if "%Domain%"=="XXXXXXXX" goto Name
if NOT "%Domain%"=="XXXXXXXX" echo.
echo Unable to Resolve FQDN. You May need to connect to the domain. 
echo.
echo    ******************Please see Below*********************
echo.
echo If the top shows you are connected to the domain and the username is XXXX
echo You are all set. The FQDN will NOT show up until logged in as a Domain User.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.


pause
echo.
echo Remember, if XXXX and Domain were correct, Please Enter N
echo.
:choice
set /P c=Do you want to open the Name/Domain Dialog Box[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :AddDomain
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :Name

:addDomain
Start /wait C:\Windows\System32\SystemPropertiesComputerName.exe
pause
goto Name
REM PE Tools Split PE Explorer and PE Resource Tuner into 2 separate Programs FYI
exit


:ChangeHostname

:: Defunct
REM Legacy, Now Running Powershell see C:\XXXXXXXXXX\Config_Bat\Domain_Add.ps1
:: SET /P PCNAME=Please enter your name: 
:: REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName /v ComputerName /t REG_SZ /d %PCNAME% /f


pause

:ChangeXXXXPassword
cls
echo Command sent to change XXX Password to XXXX
net user XXX XXXXXXX
echo.
pause
goto :MainMenu

:Name
cls
REM WMIC
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic computersystem get model /format:list') do set "SYSMODEL=%%I"
set "Line1=                          System Model: %SYSMODEL%"
echo %Line1%
reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > NUL && set OS=32BIT || set OS=64BIT

if %OS%==32BIT echo                         This is a 32bit operating system
if %OS%==64BIT echo                         This is a 64bit operating system
echo.

for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set "BIOSVer=%%A"
echo                                Bios Version: %BIOSVer%

for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic computersystem get name'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set "compName=%%A"
echo                                Hostname: %compname%
echo.
echo                              Current User: %USERNAME%
echo.
echo If FQDN does NOT appear, please check up top for Domain to verify XXXXXXX
echo                                Fully Qualified Name
whoami /FQDN
echo.
pause


goto :MainMenu
:: Checking if the batch is running with Admin Privs
goto check_Permissions




:MainMenu

Title HWD Depot Thingy



set "Window[1]=Set XXXXPassword"
set "Window[2]=Check MSI Availability"
set "Window[3]=Install Software"
set "Window[4]=Individual Install"
set "Window[5]=Post Config Check"
set "Window[6]=Open XXXXXXXX Folder"
set "Window[7]=Stop and Disable Windows Update Service"
set "Window[8]=Uninstall DDD * Will check for Acrobat XI *"
set "Window[9]=Exit"

set "Message="
cls
echo.%Message%
echo.
echo                              Current User: %USERNAME%
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic computersystem get name'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set "compName=%%A"
echo                               Hostname %compname%
echo.
echo.
echo       ******Option 1 and 2 Require Batch to be run as an Administrator******
echo.
echo                                ---Main Menu---
echo.
set "x=0"
:MenuLoop
set /a "X+=1"
if defined Window[%x%] (
call echo                             %x%. %%Window[%x%]%%
goto MenuLoop
)
echo.


:Prompt
Set "Input="
set /p "Input=HWD                        Select Which Shell Window: "

:: Validate Input
if not defined Input goto Prompt
set "Input=%Input:"=%"
set "Input=%Input:^=%"
set "Input=%Input:<=%"
set "Input=%Input:>=%"
set "Input=%Input:&=%"
set "Input=%Input:|=%"
set "Input=%Input:(=%"
set "Input=%Input:)=%"
:: No Equals
set "Input=%Input:^==%"
call :Validate %Input%

:: Process
call :Process %Input%
goto End

:Validate
set "Next=%2"
if not defined Window[%1] (
set "Message=Invalid Input: %1"
goto :MainMenu
)
if defined Next shift & goto Validate
goto :eof

:Process
set "Next=%2"
call set "Window=%%Window[%1]%%"

:: Run
if "%Window%" EQU "Set XXXXXX" goto XXXXXXXX
if "%Window%" EQU "Check MSI Availability" goto CheckMSI
if "%Window%" EQU "Install Software" goto Install
if "%Window%" EQU "Individual Install" goto IndividualInstall
if "%Window%" EQU "Post Config Check" goto PCC
if "%Window%" EQU "Open XXXXXXXX Folder" goto IST
if "%Window%" EQU "Stop and Disable Windows Update Service" goto StopWinUpdt
if "%Window%" EQU "Uninstall DDD * Will check for Acrobat XI *" goto :UninstallDDD
if "%Window%" EQU "Exit" goto :eof


:: Dumbass

:: if "%Window%" EQU "All Apps" ( )
:: Need to make this not an option

:: Prevent Double Jeopardy
set "Window[%1]="
if defined Next shift & goto Process
goto :eof

:CheckMSI
cls

if exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\SC_ClientSetup_v63134466374.msi" echo SC MSI Exists
if NOT exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\SC_ClientSetup_v63134466374.msi" echo SC MSI NULL
if exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\ampagent-7.1.62-x86_help.XXXXXXXX.com.msi" echo KACE MSI Exists
if NOT exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\ampagent-7.1.62-x86_help.XXXXXXXX.com.msi" echo KACE MSI NULL
if exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\anyconnect-win-4.4.03034-core-vpn-webdeploy-k9.exe" echo AnyConnect MSI Exists
if NOT exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\anyconnect-win-4.4.03034-core-vpn-webdeploy-k9.exe" echo AnyConnect MSI NULL
if exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\Agent_EPO2.exe" echo McAfee Agent Exe Exists
if NOT exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\Agent_EPO2.exe" echo McAfee Agent Exe NULL
if exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\2 Endpoint_Security_10_5_1\setupEP.exe" echo McAfee EPO Exe Exists
if NOT exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\2 Endpoint_Security_10_5_1\setupEP.exe" echo McAfee EPO Exe NULL
if exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\3 Adaptive_Threat_Protection_10_5_1\setupATP.exe" echo McAfee ATP Exe Exists
if NOT exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\3 Adaptive_Threat_Protection_10_5_1\setupATP.exe" echo McAfee ATP Exe NULL
if exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\4 DXL_Client_3_1_595\dxlsetup.exe" echo McAfee DXL Exe Exists
if NOT exist "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\4 DXL_Client_3_1_595\dxlsetup.exe" echo McAfee DXL Exe NULL

pause

goto :MainMenu

:StopWinUpdt
cls
echo Processing Windows Update Stop and Disable
net stop wuauserv
echo Processing Disable Command
sc config wuauserv start= disabled
echo Windows Update "Wuauserv" has been Disabled
pause
goto MainMenu

:Install


REM Query Screen Connect Exist

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{E8ABFA22-897F-4FCB-902A-4DCD400B53DC}
REM Error level 0 means installed
REM Error Level 1 Means Not Installed

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET SC=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET SC=No

REM Query KACE Exist
reg query HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Dell\KACE
cls

REM Error level 0 means installed
REM Error Level 1 Means Not Installed

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET KACE=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET KACE=No

REM Query Any Connect

reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET AnyConnect=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET AnyConnect=No



Rem Query McAfee Agent

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{80684F9A-6B01-4F3F-A8C7-C4B7BDF072F1}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET MAgent=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET MAgent=No


Rem Query McAfee Endpoint

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{4F574B83-3AE0-419F-8A3B-985C389334B4}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET Endpoint=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET Endpoint=No


Rem Query McAfee Adaptive Thread Protection

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{80B1F696-3C8F-4BBC-BD07-86CF0E37FDD2}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtection=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtection=No


Rem Query McAfee Data Exchange Layer

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{8f28453c-bec7-4d47-8152-3b8b40238dec}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET McAfeeDataExchangeLayer=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET McAfeeDataExchangeLayer=No



REM Query Standard X

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AC76BA86-1033-F400-BA7E-000000000005}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET StandardX=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET StandardX=No

REM Query Standard XI

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AC76BA86-1033-FFFF-7760-000000000006}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET StandardXI=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET StandardXI=No


REM We have to Grab the Dword, which is in Hex, and Convert it to Decimal, and store it as a Var

for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\FS StreetSmart\Field Sales Professional"  /V "salesperson ID"  ^|findstr 

/ri "Salesperson ID"') do set /a ID=%%a + 0

REM Output all Results

:ProgramsListed
cls
echo.
echo Program list
echo.
echo SC Installed:                 %SC%
echo Kace Installed:               %Kace%
echo AnyConnect Installed:         %AnyConnect%
echo McAfee Agent Installed:       %MAgent%
echo Endpoint Installed:           %Endpoint%
echo McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtect:  %McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtection%
echo McAfee Data Exchange Layer:   %McAfeeDataExchangeLayer%
echo Adobe Standard X Installed:   %StandardX%
echo Adobe Standard XI Installed:  %StandardXI%
echo.
echo.
echo User:             %USERNAME%
echo XXX Sales Person ID:     %ID%
echo.
echo.
echo.



:Installchoice
set /P c=Do you want to add to Install Non-installed Software[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :InstallSoft
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :MainMenu

goto :ProgramsListed
:InstallSoft

REM Query Screen Connect
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{E8ABFA22-897F-4FCB-902A-4DCD400B53DC}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 Set SC=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 Set SC=No


REM Query KACE Exist
reg query HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Dell\KACE
cls

REM Error level 0 means installed
REM Error Level 1 Means Not Installed

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET KACE=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET KACE=No

REM Query Any Connect

reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET AnyConnect=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET AnyConnect=No



Rem Query McAfee Agent

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{80684F9A-6B01-4F3F-A8C7-C4B7BDF072F1}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET MAgent=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET MAgent=No


Rem Query McAfee Endpoint

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{4F574B83-3AE0-419F-8A3B-985C389334B4}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET Endpoint=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET Endpoint=No


Rem Query McAfee Adaptive Thread Protection

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{80B1F696-3C8F-4BBC-BD07-86CF0E37FDD2}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtection=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtection=No


Rem Query McAfee Data Exchange Layer

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{8f28453c-bec7-4d47-8152-3b8b40238dec}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET McAfeeDataExchangeLayer=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET McAfeeDataExchangeLayer=No



REM Query Standard X

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AC76BA86-1033-F400-BA7E-000000000005}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET StandardX=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET StandardX=No

REM Query Standard XI

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AC76BA86-1033-FFFF-7760-000000000006}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET StandardXI=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET StandardXI=No

if /I "%SC%" EQU "No" goto :InstallSC
if /I "%SC%" EQU "Yes" echo Screen Connect Already Installed
if /I "%Kace%" EQU "No" goto :InstallKace
if /I "%Kace%" EQU "Yes" echo Kace Already Installed
if /I "%AnyConnect%" EQU "No" goto :InstallAnyC
if /I "%AnyConnect%" EQU "YES" echo AnyConnect Already Installed
if /I "%MAgent%" EQU "Yes" echo McAfee Agent Already Installed
if /I "%MAgent%" EQU "No" goto :InstallMAgnt
if /I "%Endpoint%" EQU "Yes" echo Endpoint Already Installed
if /I "%Endpoint%" EQU "No" goto :InstallEPO
if /I "%McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtection%" EQU "Yes" echo McAfee Adaptive Threat Protection Already Installed
if /I "%McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtection%" EQU "No" goto :InstallATP
if /I "%McAfeeDataExchangeLayer%" EQU "Yes" echo McAfee Exchange Data Layer Installed
if /I "%McAfeeDataExchangeLayer%" EQU "No" goto :InstallDXL


pause
goto :MainMenu
Pause
```

---

```
Call "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\4 DXL_Client_3_1_595\dxlsetup.exe"
pause

:EndInstall
Goto :InstallSoft

goto :eof






:IndividualInstall



Title HWD Depot Thingy
:MainMenuIndiv

set "Window[1]=SC"
set "Window[2]=Kace"
set "Window[3]=Cisco AnyConnect"
set "Window[4]=McAfee Agent"
set "Window[5]=McAfee EPO"
set "Window[6]=McAfee ATP"
set "Window[7]=McAfee DXL"
set "Window[8]=Adobe Standard * PLEASE DO MANUALLY *"
set "Window[9]=Exit"

set "Message="
cls
echo.%Message%
echo.
echo                              Current User: %USERNAME%
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic computersystem get name'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set "compName=%%A"
echo                               Hostname %compname%
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                                ---Main Menu---
echo.
set "x=0"
:MenuLoopA
set /a "X+=1"
if defined Window[%x%] (
call echo                             %x%. %%Window[%x%]%%
goto MenuLoopA
)
echo.


:PromptA
Set "Input="
set /p "Input=HWD                        Select Which Shell Window: "

:: Validate Input
if not defined Input goto Prompt
set "Input=%Input:"=%"
set "Input=%Input:^=%"
set "Input=%Input:<=%"
set "Input=%Input:>=%"
set "Input=%Input:&=%"
set "Input=%Input:|=%"
set "Input=%Input:(=%"
set "Input=%Input:)=%"
:: No Equals
set "Input=%Input:^==%"
call :ValidateA %Input%

:: Process
call :ProcessA %Input%
goto End

:ValidateA
set "Next=%2"
if not defined Window[%1] (
set "Message=Invalid Input: %1"
goto :MainMenuIndiv
)
if defined Next shift & goto ValidateA
goto :eof

:ProcessA
set "Next=%2"
call set "Window=%%Window[%1]%%"

:: Run
if "%Window%" EQU "SC" goto InstallSCb
if "%Window%" EQU "Kace" goto InstallKACEb
if "%Window%" EQU "Cisco AnyConnect" goto InstallAnyCb
if "%Window%" EQU "McAfee Agent" goto InstallMAgntb
if "%Window%" EQU "McAfee EPO" goto InstallEPOb
if "%Window%" EQU "McAfee ATP" goto InstallATPb
if "%Window%" EQU "McAfee DXL" goto InstallDXLb
if "%Window%" EQU "Adobe Standard * PLEASE DO MANUALLY *" goto :IndividualInstall
if "%Window%" EQU "Exit" goto :MainMenu



:InstallSCb
Start /WAIT C:\XXXXXXXXXX\SC_ClientSetup_v63134466374.msi
set /P c=Do you want to Install Screen Connect[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" echo Screen Connect Installing
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :InstallKACE

:InstallKACEb
Start /WAIT C:\XXXXXXXXXX\ampagent-7.1.62-x86_help.asmXXXX.com.msi
echo KACE Installing
goto :IndividualInstall
pause

:InstallAnyCb
echo Any Connect Installing
start /WAIT C:\XXXXXXXXXX\anyconnect-win-4.4.03034-core-vpn-webdeploy-k9.exe
Goto :IndividualInstall

REM Installation Function to set up McAfee Agent
:InstallMAgntb
echo Installing McAfee Agent
Start /WAIT "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\Agent_EPO2.exe"
Goto :IndividualInstall

:InstallEPOb
echo Installing McAfee Endpoint
Start /WAIT "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\2 Endpoint_Security_10_5_1\setupEP.exe"
Goto :IndividualInstall

:InstallATPb
echo Installing McAfee Adaptive Threat Protection
Start /WAIT "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\3 Adaptive_Threat_Protection_10_5_1\setupATP.exe"
Goto :IndividualInstall

:InstallDXLb
echo Installing McAfee Data Exchange Layer
Start /WAIT "C:\XXXXXXXXXX\McAfee Installers\4 DXL_Client_3_1_595\dxlsetup.exe"
Goto :IndividualInstall

goto :eof







:: Dumbass

:: if "%Window%" EQU "All Apps" ( )
:: Need to make this not an option

:: Prevent Double Jeopardy
set "Window[%1]="
if defined Next shift & goto Process
goto :eof

||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

:PCC



REM Query Screen Connect
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{E8ABFA22-897F-4FCB-902A-4DCD400B53DC}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 Set SC=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 Set SC=No





REM Query KACE Exist
reg query HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Dell\KACE
cls

REM Error level 0 means installed
REM Error Level 1 Means Not Installed

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET KACE=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET KACE=No

REM Query Any Connect

reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET AnyConnect=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET AnyConnect=No



Rem Query McAfee Agent

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{80684F9A-6B01-4F3F-A8C7-C4B7BDF072F1}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET MAgent=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET MAgent=No


Rem Query McAfee Endpoint

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{4F574B83-3AE0-419F-8A3B-985C389334B4}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET Endpoint=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET Endpoint=No


Rem Query McAfee Adaptive Thread Protection

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{80B1F696-3C8F-4BBC-BD07-86CF0E37FDD2}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtection=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtection=No


Rem Query McAfee Data Exchange Layer

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{8f28453c-bec7-4d47-8152-3b8b40238dec}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET McAfeeDataExchangeLayer=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET McAfeeDataExchangeLayer=No



REM Query Standard X

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AC76BA86-1033-F400-BA7E-000000000005}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET StandardX=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET StandardX=No

REM Query Standard XI


reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AC76BA86-1033-FFFF-7760-000000000006}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET StandardXI=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET StandardXI=No


for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\XXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXXXX"  /V "salesperson ID"  ^|findstr 

/ri "Salesperson ID"') do set /a ID=%%a + 0

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto SkipF
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 echo XXXXXXXXXXXX is Installed BUT not configured for the user.



:SkipF




echo.
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
echo                          Installed Software
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
if /I "%SC%" EQU "Yes" echo SC Installed
if /I "%SC%" EQU "No" goto :InstallSC
if /I "%Kace%" EQU "No" goto :InstallKace
if /I "%Kace%" EQU "Yes" echo Kace Installed
if /I "%AnyConnect%" EQU "No" goto :InstallAnyC
if /I "%AnyConnect%" EQU "YES" echo AnyConnect Installed
if /I "%MAgent%" EQU "Yes" echo McAfee Agent Installed
if /I "%MAgent%" EQU "No" goto :InstallMAgnt
if /I "%Endpoint%" EQU "Yes" echo Endpoint Installed
if /I "%Endpoint%" EQU "No" goto :InstallEPO
if /I "%McAfeeAdaptiveThreatProtection%" EQU "Yes" echo McAfee Adaptive Threat Protection Installed
if /I "%Endpoint%" EQU "No" goto :InstallATP
if /I "%McAfeeDataExchangeLayer%" EQU "Yes" echo McAFee Data Exchange Layer Installed
if /I "%Endpoint%" EQU "No" goto :InstallDX
echo.
echo.
echo User:             %USERNAME%
echo XXXXXXXXXXX ID:     %ID%
echo.
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo                            ALL SOFTWARE INSTALLED
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pause
cls
REM Query Dell Digital Delivery

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{693A23FB-F28B-4F7A-A720-4C1263F97F43}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET DDD=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET DDD=No

if /I "%DDD%" EQU "Yes" echo NOTICE
echo    Dell Digital Delivery is Installed.

set /P c=Would you like to uninstall it[Y/N]?
if /I "%C%" EQU "Y" start /wait C:\Windows\System32\MsiExec.exe /I{693A23FB-F28B-4F7A-A720-4C1263F97F43}
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :MainMenu
pause

goto :MainMenu


goto :eof

:IST
explorer.exe C:\XXXXXXXXXX
pause
goto MainMenu

:UninstallDDD

REM Query Standard X

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AC76BA86-1033-F400-BA7E-000000000005}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET StandardXb=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET StandardXb=No

REM Query Standard XI

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AC76BA86-1033-FFFF-7760-000000000006}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET StandardXIb=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET StandardXIb=No

for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\FS StreetSmart\Field Sales Professional"  /V "salesperson ID"  ^|findstr 

/ri "Salesperson ID"') do set /a ID=%%a + 0


:AdobeXCheck
echo Adobe Program Check
echo.
if /I "%Standardxb%" EQU "Yes" echo Adobe Standard X Installed
goto SkipA
if /I "%Standardxb%" EQU "No" goto :AdobeXICheck
pause

:AdobeXICheck
if /I "%StandardXIb%" EQU "Yes" echo Adobe Standard XI Installed
goto SkipA
if /I "%StandardXIb%" EQU "No" goto :NeitherLogic
goto SkipA

:Neitherlogic
if /I "%StandardXIb%" EQU "Yes" echo Adobe Standard X NULL
if /I "%STandardXIb%" EQU "YES" echo Adobe Standard XI Installed
if /I "%StandardXIb%" EQU "No" echo Neither Adobe X nor XI are installed!!!!

echo.
echo Please check above for Adobe Installations



set /P c=Do you still want to uninstall DDD[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto UninstalDDDnow
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" echo Going back to main menu
Timeout 5
goto MainMenu


:UninstalDDDnow
cls
echo Uninstalling Dell Digital Delivery
echo.
CALL "C:\Windows\System32\MsiExec.exe" /I{693A23FB-F28B-4F7A-A720-4C1263F97F43}
echo.

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{693A23FB-F28B-4F7A-A720-4C1263F97F43}
cls

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET DDDpost=Yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET DDDpost=No

if /I "%DDDpost%" EQU "Yes" echo Dell Digital Delivery is STILL showing Installed. Please check manually
if /I "%DDDpost%" EQU "No" echo Dell Digital Delivery has succesfully been uninstalled!
pause
goto MainMenu
pause
```

Comment: I will try my best to answer as quickly as possible, but usually only during the work day. 8-5 EST.

Comment: At the moment your comment that you `know how to regquery to search within a key for a value` appears to be unrealistic. When you get to work, grab a coffee, open up a command prompt, type `Reg Query /?`, press enter and start reading.

Comment: I will just use /S then, I did not want to use that, but I guess I have no choice.